# How to achieve this model

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, c1flexgrid

I have a table like this

[image: I have a table like this]

I am trying to achieve a table like this:
[image]

this was my query.

```
select name,token , sum(qty) [Qty],sum(amount)from #temp 
 group by token,name
```

tried like this..

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   (SELECT  name,
               qty,amt,
               Token
               FROM   #temp1
       ) AS D
       PIVOT(Sum(amt)
            FOR Token IN ([10],[20],[100],[40],[5])) AS P
```

it is not working though.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve it by the following statement:

```
SELECT 
    [Name],
    SUM((CASE WHEN [Token] = 10 THEN [QTY] ELSE 0 END)) AS Token_10_QTY,
    SUM((CASE WHEN [Token] = 10 THEN [amt] ELSE 0 END)) AS Token_10_amt,
    SUM((CASE WHEN [Token] = 50 THEN [QTY] ELSE 0 END)) AS Token_50_QTY,
    SUM((CASE WHEN [Token] = 50 THEN [amt] ELSE 0 END)) AS Token_50_amt,
    SUM((CASE WHEN [Token] = 100 THEN [QTY] ELSE 0 END)) AS Token_100_QTY,
    SUM((CASE WHEN [Token] = 100 THEN [amt] ELSE 0 END)) AS Token_100_amt
FROM 
    #temp1
GROUP BY
    [Name]
```

assuming your columns `QTY` and `amt` are `NOT NULL`.
I hope it will help you some way.